# How can we calculate the amount of volume of a CSG object?

Tags: openscad, csg

In OpenSCAD I implement the following animation:

```
WhR = 1.5; // wheel radius
WhH = 6; // wheel height
WpR = 1; // workpiece radius
WpH = 6; // workpiece height

$fn = 30;
pos = position($t);

intersection(){
rotate([0,-90,0]){
cylinder(WpH, WpR,WpR);
}

translate([pos,0,-2.5]){
cylinder(WhH,WhR,WhR);
}
}

function position(t) = -7.5 + t;
```

My question is, how can I calculate and export the "amount of volume" during the intersection? [If you know how to do that in VTK or in any other library, please enlighten me!]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OpenSCAD doesn't have support for this directly.

[RapCAD](https://github.com/GilesBathgate/RapCAD/blob/master/doc/user_guide.asciidoc#bounds) does though, through the use of bound$():

```
bound$()cube(10);
```